# Duplicate permission setting instructions

Tags: laravel, aws-code-deploy

I'm trying to use CodeDeploy's permission handling stuff to deploy a Laravel app but I'm constantly getting a message saying /home/tether/storage/app has duplicate permissions. To my eyes, it looks like the except should make it only one rule.

```
yaml
permissions:
  - object: /home/tether
    pattern: "**"
    except: [
      storage,
      storage/app,
      storage/framework,
      storage/framework/cache,
      storage/framework/sessions,
      storage/framework/views,
      storage/framework,
      storage/logs
    ]
    owner: tether
    group: tether
  - object: /home/tether/storage
    pattern: "**"
    owner: tether
    group: tether
    mode: 755
    type:
      - directory
```

Comment: I don't know anything about aws, but `storage/framework` is in the except array twice if that matters.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try adding

```
type:
  - directory
```

to your /home/tether object? That way the codedeploy-agent would exclude the files listed under that directory (in the exception list) while setting permissions.